# Express the WhiteNoiseProcess in number form

Tags: output-formatting

I have this function
[image]

However, I want to export its values so that I can plot the graph in the TecPlot

May I know How to achieve that.

Comment: The points in `data` are the values you want. See the documentation for `Export`.

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Export](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) and [Importing and Exporting Data](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingData.html)

```
points = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, Range[0, 2 \[Pi], .01]}];
ListLinePlot[points]
```

[image]

```
Export["Export_Values_1.csv", points]
```

> "Export_Values_1.csv"

You'll find the file with:

```
SystemOpen[DirectoryName[AbsoluteFileName["Export_Values_1.csv"]]]
```